# Cannot set UDTs in a jooq insert, consistently getting a StackOverflowError

Tags: postgresql, jooq

The SQL is pretty simple:

```
CREATE TYPE audit_fields AS (
    creation_time_ms BIGINT
);

CREATE TABLE users(
    ...
    audit AUDIT_FIELDS NOT NULL
);
```

These are two ways I have tried to do this:

```
UsersRecord getRecord() {
    return new UsersRecord()
        .setSomeField(...)
        .setOtherField(...)
        .setAudit(new AuditFieldsRecord(System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

create.insertInto(Tables.USERS)
    .set(getRecord())
    .execute();
```

And, this:

```
create.insertInto(Tables.USERS)
    .set(getRecord())
    .set(Tables.USERS.AUDIT, new AuditFieldsRecord(System.currentTimemillis()))
    .execute();
```

I am simply getting a `StackOverflowError`, with the following block repeating throughout (obviously an infinite-recursion):

```
at org.jooq.impl.UDTConstant.<init>(UDTConstant.java:62)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:12781)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:12732)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.inline(DSL.java:12590)
at org.jooq.impl.UDTRecordImpl.toString(UDTRecordImpl.java:141)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.name(AbstractParam.java:104)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:78)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:74)
at org.jooq.impl.UDTConstant.<init>(UDTConstant.java:62)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:12781)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:12732)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.inline(DSL.java:12590)
at org.jooq.impl.UDTRecordImpl.toString(UDTRecordImpl.java:141)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.name(AbstractParam.java:104)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:78)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:74)
at org.jooq.impl.UDTConstant.<init>(UDTConstant.java:62)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:12781)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:12732)
at org.jooq.impl.DSL.inline(DSL.java:12590)
at org.jooq.impl.UDTRecordImpl.toString(UDTRecordImpl.java:141)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.name(AbstractParam.java:104)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:78)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:74)
at org.jooq.impl.UDTConstant.<init>(UDTConstant.java:62)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What jOOQ version are you using?

Comment: @LukasEder 3.9.3

Comment: Quick correction. It turns out I had 3.7.0 on my classpath. Once I fixed it to 3.9.3, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that exists in older versions of Jooq 3.7.0. For projects who are using that version and cannot migrate easily to newer versions, this question might be a starting point, so I am not voting to close it (other's are requested to if they see fit).

Upgrading to a later version of jooq fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Indeed, this issue was fixed in 3.8.0 (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4749) and not yet merged to versions 3.7.x or older.